# Hardy Spaces on the unit disk and $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: soft-question, functional-analysis

Is there a connection between the Hardy Spaces on the unit disk and on $\mathbb R^n$?.

If so, can we use results from the Hardy Spaces on the unit disk to prove $(H^1)^* = \text{BMO}$?

Further, what is the most fruitful way to define $H^1$ on $\mathbb R^n$ but avoiding (bounded) distributions? I was writing something for a project and this would be the only point where I would use them. Of course, I could take the completion of the $C_c^\infty$ functions in the $H^1$-norm, but is this workable enough?

Comment: Have you looked at the original paper by Fefferman and Stein? [Read the masters!] I have read (parts of) it a long time ago and I think it uses singular integral methods (and Hardy-Littlewood maximal functions and the like) for that. Here's a link to it http://dx.doi.org/10.1007%2FBF02392215

Comment: With "for that" I meant the duality. I just leafed through the paper again and you should definitely have a look at it.

Comment: @Theo: Thanks! The duality proof looks a bit different from the one I know (from Grafakos' book). I will definitely read it completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer on the OP's request:

Have you looked at the original paper by Fefferman and Stein? [Read the masters!] I have read (parts of) it a long time ago and I think it uses singular integral methods (and Hardy-Littlewood maximal functions and the like) for that. Here's a [link to it](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007%2FBF02392215).